# Deleting files that matches a particular naming criteria in ansible

Tags: ansible

In ansible i need to delete files from a folder that matches a specific naming criteria: like all files and folders that starts with abc

Want to delete /abc*.*

i have used below task to remove all files:

```
 - name: Removes all files
   file:
     path: "<folder path>/root/"
     state: absent
```

However i need to be able to specify a criteria here somewhere to delete only those files and folders  with names that start with abc-*.

I have already tried to use :

```
- name: Removes files that start with abc
  file:
     path: "{{item}}"
     state: absent
  with_fileglob:
     - <path>/abc*
```

But this is not matching any files/folders.

I have also tried :

```
 - name: Finds files and folders
     find:
        paths: "<path>/"
        patterns: "abc*"
        recurse: yes
     register: result

 - name: Removes  files and folders
   file:
     path: "{{item.path}}"
     state: absent
   with_items: '{{result.files}}'
```

This as well doesnt return any files or folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with_fileglob` is run on control host, not on remote host. Your `find` is missing `use_regex`.

**Using `find` module (preferred)**

```
 - name: Finds files and folders
     find:
        paths: "<path>/"
        patterns: "abc*"
        recurse: yes
        use_regex: yes
     register: result

 - name: Removes  files and folders
   file:
     path: "{{item.path}}"
     state: absent
   with_items: '{{result.files}}'
```

**Solution using `shell` module**

```
  tasks:
  - name: Lists files and folders
    shell: find <your-path>
    register: matched_files_dirs

  - name: Removes files and folders
    file: path="{{item}}" state=absent
    with_items: matched_files_dirs.stdout_lines
```

Comment: Thank you for guiding. My final solution is this shell command:
find <path> -path 'abc*' -delete